Lean 4: How to destruct recursive definitions in proofs
I don't understand how to handle recursive definitions in proofs.
How can I fix the sorry in the following code? I thought replacing sorry with h should do the trick, but it doesn't.
theorem th (is_core: α → Prop) (a₀:α) (h: is_core a₀) (k: α → α) : True :=
  let rec is_layer (a : α) : Nat → Prop
    | Nat.zero => is_core a
    | Nat.succ n => ∃ a₀:α, (a = k a₀ ∧ is_layer a₀ n)

  have h1: is_layer a₀ 0 := sorry

  -- ...

  trivial
```


I think this is just a limitation of let rec, you generally can't unfold the local/auxiliary def: https://leanprover.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/113488-general/topic/How.20to.20reduce.20a.20goal/near/444873620
In this case you can extract is_layer as a normal def, in which case h is sufficient.
def is_layer (is_core : α → Prop) (k : α → α) (a : α) : Nat → Prop
  | Nat.zero => is_core a
  | Nat.succ n => ∃ a₀:α, (a = k a₀ ∧ is_layer is_core k a₀ n)

theorem th (is_core: α → Prop) (a₀:α) (h: is_core a₀) (k: α → α) : True :=
  have h1: is_layer is_core k a₀ 0 := h
  trivial
```

